# Printing array elements in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Since StoreEval and getEval does not work so I added javascript as in image one
Previously I used to do as

```
storeEval   new Array("car","bus"); vehicles
getEval myitems=0;
```

to use the loop

[image]

Output is as

```
Running 'new array'
13:43:33
1.store on new Array("car","bus"); with value vehicles OK
13:43:34
2.executeScript on return 1 with value myitems OK
13:43:34
3.while on ${myitems}<3 OK
13:43:34
4.store on myitems with value myvar OK
13:43:34
echo: javascript{storedVars['vehicles'][storedVars['myvar']]}
13:43:34
6.executeScript on return ${myitems}+1 with value myitems OK
13:43:34
echo: javascript{storedVars['vehicles'][storedVars['myvar']]}
13:43:35
7.end OK
```

instead of printing the values of array elements its printing javascript
also when i tried with

```
myitems < storedVars['vehicles'].length
```

to get the length it does not work.

Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `store` command simply assigns the value in **Target** to the variable in **Value**. In your code, you've created a variable named vehicles that contains the string "new Array("car", "bus");".

You can create your array like this:

**Command** = `execute script` | **Target** = `return["car", "bus"]` | **Value** = `vehicles`

Then print your array elements using a for each loop. The end result would look like this:

[For each loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef6US.png)

You can read more about creating, reading, and adding to Selenium IDE arrays [here](https://sitegrammar.com/selenium-ide-arrays/).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129404/implementing-array-elements-in-selenium
how can the values of the array be passed in the text box via its CSS or ID or anything?

Comment: Please send me a screenshot or a .side file containing the full code.

Comment: Screenshot is present in the link above.

Comment: Try to initialize your array like this: `execute script | return ["car", "bus"] | vehicles`, then replace `send keys | vehicles | ${iterator}` with `send keys | css=.XTCL0| ${iterator}` to write each array element to the textbox. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Glad I could help!