# Implementing array elements in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Post My previous question in 
[Printing array elements in Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017355/printing-array-elements-in-selenium-ide)

I tried to print the array elements in text box 
the command is as follows:

[image]

while sending the values of vehicles to iterator so that I can further enter the values as ${KEY_ENTER}with the array elements it does not pass the value of the vehicle to the iterator.

Is there an alternate way where I can send the array values so that I can target css=.XTCLo to that array elements.

I even tried by executing

```
type | css=.XTCL0| ${iterator}
```

But it just enters ${iterator} instead rather than value by doing so.

So tried using send keys command but it didn't work can someone help me with this?

Output

```
Running '1st (1)'
15:16:08
1.open on / OK
15:16:09
2.executeScript on ["car","bus"] with value vehicles OK
15:16:09
3.forEach on vehicles with value iterator OK
15:16:11
4.store on myitems with value myvar OK
15:16:11
5.click on css=.Fifk5 .\_6q-tv OK
15:16:11
6.Trying to find vehicles... Failed:
15:16:12
Implicit Wait timed out after 30000ms
Warning implicit locators are deprecated, please change the locator to id=vehicles
15:16:15
'1st (1)' ended with 1 error(s)
```

Comment: I think using id=vehicles as per suggestion is meaningless

Comment: I even tried by entering
send keys | css=.XTCL0|${iterator} 
But it just enters ${iterator} instead rather than value as previous type case.

Comment: Looked at your both question..you want to enter data on the web textbox where other in a row where a condition is matched , can you share some code which you have done..

Comment: @HietshKumar I used Selenium IDE for entering the array elements to the text box.
I had added it as Screenshot in question does that help?
Please do let me know if I ought to add something more
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I executed `script | return ["car", "bus"] | vehicles`, and 
 replaced `send keys | vehicles | ${iterator}` with `send keys | css=.XTCL0| ${iterator}`
this fixed the issue